# How to shuffle a list of sets so that each item a set never appears in the same set twice?

Tags: probability

I tried to make the title of this question sound as mathematical as possible, but in layperson's terms (ie: me), lets say we have the following scenario:

There is a three course dinner with 300 guests in a hotel. Each table has a maximum capacity of 12 seats, which means there are 25 tables total.

The task I have (not a homework assignment, but from a real event taking place in a month or so) is to ensure that:

a) at the end of each course every guest switches to another table
b) they never sit at the same table twice
c) they never sit with the same person more than once

Another way of saying the above is that each person should sit with exactly 33 different people during the course of the meal. (11 new people at each table for each course).

My feeling, and experience from trying, is that this not possible with guestCount= 300 and tableCapacity=12, but would be completely possible with guestCount=300 and seatsPerTable=6.

What I first tried was for each subsequent course to iterate over each member of the first table, and move each one to a new table based on their position on the their table. This would result in something like:

Table 1, Seat 1 -> Table 2, Seat 1
Table 1, Seat 2 -> Table 3, Seat 1
...
Table 2, Seat 1 -> Table 3, Seat 2
etc

This works perfectly for 2 courses (with 300 guests, 12 per table). But fails on course 3.

So then because I have no clue how to actually prove/disprove this mathematically, I took the state after 2 courses and for the third course I simply tried 100k times to assign each user to a random table that they hadn't sat on before.

After 100k attempts, the best I could get was that 176/300 sat with 33 different people. The rest were a mix of 29-32.

So, I am not necessarily looking for a solution to this problem but some pointers in what direction to take to prove or disprove it is actually possible?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: If the guests are named by their first-course table $T$ and seat $S$ (and we don't change their names as they move): how about have each guest move $S$ tables forward after their first course and again after their second course? So guest $(T,S)$ sits at tables $T,T+S,T+2S$ in that order (where table numbers are taken modulo $25$).

Comment: Sorry, if you saw my previous comments, I missed the comma in your suggestion. I will try it and let you know!

Comment: And it worked, of course it did. :)

And actually, the only difference between my first approach I mentioned earlier and yours was the "and we dont change their names as they move". So atleast I was on to something! 

Instead, at each iteration I was taking the most recent T & S, not the original, if that makes sense.

Could you post this as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: And, this has blown my mind....how simple the solution, and my code is, compared to the original that didn't even work. Would you have any recommended resources for this kind of thing for my level? My issue really is that I lack even the fundamental terminology knowledge required to perform an effective google search when I come across such problems.